# wrong entry in .nls file using nomencl

Tags: miktex, makeindex, nomencl

I'm writing a large report using MikTex and I'd like to add a nomenclature.
I successfully created .nls and .nlo files. However, I forgot a $ in one of the entries and this generates the following error:

"! Missing $ inserted"

I have found the source of the error in my code and fixed it. However, it seems that this did not change the .nls file. Therefore I cannot compile my document.

How can I correct the .nls file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to delete the .nls file and recreate it with makeindex. You need to re-run makeindex any time there's a change in your nomenclature.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The if I delete the nls fille and re-create it, I would still get the same error. Even if the new version of the nls file no longer has the original mistake....